# Registration Form Checking The Two Password Are Matching

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make this registration script tell the user when the passwords they have entered are not matching.

and i use this code:

```
 if ($_POST['pass' != 'pass2'])
 {
  echo
   ("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
 }
```

please help me to correct my coding. :-(
thanks so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't reference both the variables inside the same $_POST

```
if ($_POST['pass']!= $_POST['pass2'])
 {
     echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($_POST['pass']!= $_POST['pass2'])
 {
     echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
 }
```

.. i will use this code. and it also works. :-)

.. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You should also check if the passwords were not left empty or if they are not just blank spaces. Otherwise, two uncompleted fields are valid.

```
if(trim($_POST['pass'])=='' || trim($_POST['pass2'])=='')
{
    echo('All fields are required!');
}
else if($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2'])
{
    echo('Passwords do not match!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the post you cannot reference both. So try this:

```
if(($_POST["pass"])!=($_POST["pass2"])){
    echo"Oops! Password did not match! Try again.";
}
```